# IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite Different Domains pointed to a single site

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have a single site at www.domain1.com. It's a PHP site being hosted on a Windows 2008/IIS 7.5 box. I need to set up www.domain2.com so that users are redirected to www.domain1.com/subfolder. To the user, they still see www.domain2.com in the address bar but are looking at the www.domain1.com/subfolder.

Any help on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use IIS [Application Request Routing and Url Rewrite modules](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/).  This walkthrough describes almost exactly what you are trying to achieve.